# Regex for url with port in Objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, url

Here is the code I'm using, it validates 99% of the urls I give it, but it fails when there is a ":port" after an IP address in the URL.

```
-(BOOL) validateUrl: (NSString *) candidate {


//NSString *urlRegEx=@"(http|https)://(((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+)|(";
NSString *urlRegEx = @"^(http|https|ftp)\://(([a-zA-Z0-9-.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})|([0-2]*\d*\d\.[0-2]*\d*\d\.[0-2]*\d*\d\.[0-2]*\d*\d))(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9-._\?\,\'/\+&%\$#\=~])*[^.\,)(\s]$";
NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx]; 
return [urlTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
```

}

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use `NSURL`? Try creating a URL with `URLWithString:` and if it returns nil, your URL was malformed. If you don’t get nil in return, then you can check the host, port, etc.

Comment: I've read about this earlier and I tried to do that, but I was having trouble. How would you implement this?

Comment: I've tried to implement this, but it accespts strings that don't have HTTP:// in front when it shouldn't. any ideas?

Comment: @Lance - You could just check the beginning of the string.. if([[ServerAddress substringToIndex:7 ] isEqualToString:@"http://"])

Comment: I've tested using `NSURL` with `http://192.168.1..88`, but it returns not nil... Seems uncorrect. :(