# Validate URL on iPhone

Tags: iphone, regex, validation, url

I was trying to validate URL links using regex, but not all the links are being completely identified. Can you please help me out?

I want the links to follow the pattern:

```
http://www.abcdef.org/xyz/content.aspx?menu id=190&id=3214
```

Comment: Define 'validate'. In other words, do you simply wish to assure the target is a legal URI or that it conforms to a specific pattern? And for the record, the example URI you provide is not legal as it contains an un-escaped space.

Comment: hey sorry its menu_id. and the url validation should accept all the patterns

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are looking for a regular expression to match urls with a specific pattern:

You can use something like this to match `http://www.abcdef.org/xyz/content.aspx?menu id=190&id=3214`:

```
http://.*?/[a-zA-z]+/content.aspx\?menu id=\d+?&id=\d+
```

Comment: thanx for your reply, but can you please tell me how can i go with the more generic pattern, which can recognise any pattern of url.

Answer (score 0):

[Regex for url with port in Objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225667/regex-for-url-with-port-in-objective-c)

It works well if don't have port number.

```
-(BOOL) validateUrl: (NSString *) candidate {

NSString *urlRegEx = @"^(http|https|ftp)\://(([a-zA-Z0-9-.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})|([0-2]*\d*\d\.[0-2]*\d*\d\.[0-2]*\d*\d\.[0-2]*\d*\d))(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9-._\?\,\'/\+&%\$#\=~])*[^.\,)(\s]$";
NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx]; 
return [urlTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
```